# Using Constants in Settings.py

Tags: django

Can I use a variable declared in the Django project's `settings.py` in one of my module files?

For instance, using `DATABASE_HOST = 'databasename'`?

I'm trying to get the name of the server the application is currently deployed on you see.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You certainly can... it's encouraged, in fact. To use it, import the settings from django.conf (this imports your project's settings):

```
from django.conf import settings
print "My database host is %s" % settings.DATABASE_HOST
```

The documentation on [Using settings in Python code](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code) explains why this works, and why this is preferable over importing the the `settings.py` module directly.

Comment: for some constants, it would be interesting to use getattr()

getattr(settings, "ITEMS_PER_PAGE", 25)

Answer (score 4):

yes

```
from django.conf import settings

print settings.MY_SETTINGS_VAR
```